# Is there a widely accepted definition of the width of a neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, terminology

The depth of a neural network is equal to *the total number of layers in the neural network (excluding the input layer by convention)*. A neural network with "many layers" is called a *deep* neural network.

On the other hand, the width is the name of a property of a layer in a neural network: it is equal to the number of neurons in that particular layer. So, it may be apt to use the phrase "the width of a layer in a neural network".

But, is it valid to use the phrase "width of a neural network"?

I got this doubt because the phrase "wide neural network" is widely used. The phrase gives the impression that the width is a property of a neural network. So, I am wondering whether the width of a neural network has a definition. For example, say, the width of a neural network is the number of neurons in the widest layer of that neural network.

Comment: I changed a little bit your post. I think your question was more what I put in the title, i.e. you were wondering if there is a widely accepted definition of the "width of a neural network". Feel free to change your post again.

Answer (score 5):

The width of a neural network *layer* is an agreed upon term.

According to Lou et al., in the paper [The Expressive Power of Neural Networks: A View from the Width](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2017/file/32cbf687880eb1674a07bf717761dd3a-Paper.pdf) (page 4), **the width of a neural network is the width of the widest layer of the neural network**.

> The architecture of neural networks often specified by the width and the depth of the networks. The depth $h$ of a network is defined as its number of layers (including output layer but excluding input
> layer); while **the width $d_m$ of a network is defined to be the maximal number of nodes in a layer**
> <sub>(emphasis added)</sub>

So, I would caution you to be careful with how you use the phrase "the width of a neural network", due to interpretability and scale, and the fact that neural networks often contain layers with varying numbers of neurons, depending on the layer.

From this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_width_limits_of_neural_networks) on "Large width limits of neural networks":

> The number of neurons in a layer is called the layer width.

From a nice [machine learning resource page](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-configure-the-number-of-layers-and-nodes-in-a-neural-network/)

> Finally, there are terms used to describe the shape and capability of a neural network; for example:
>
> - Size: The number of nodes in the model.
> - Width: The number of nodes in a specific layer.

> A node [is] also called a neuron or Perceptron

Comment: I edited your answer to, hopefully, improve its clarity. I would remove the part "From this wikipedia page ..." until the end of your answer because the OP already knows that we can talk about "the width of a layer". That's a pretty much standard definition, so there's no need to say that again. He's also aware of what "depth" means.